# Sheet / Range Select (combined) not working

Tags: excel, vba

Something has changed in my VBA that is not allowing me to complete certain routines.  I have listed a very simple example below.  If anyone has experienced this I would be really appreciate any support in resolving this issue.

- Simple example of issue:

When I use the following code it works fine.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B3").Select
```

When I combine them I get a "1004" error

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Select
```

I checked the reference/document library and nothing appears to have changed in here.  It has to be something simple but I just can't put my finger on it.

Comment: This seriously should work...  what OS and version of Excel are you on?

Comment: Also, is your code in a module, associated with a worksheet or somewhere else?  I suppose if this is within a worksheet, I can see why this *might* fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you absolutely **must** do it in a single line of code then swap the Select for an `Application.GoTo` which accepts both worksheet and cell range.

```
application.goto range("Sheet1!B3")
```

However, it is almost never necessary (and most often counter-productive) to use the [Range .Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197597.aspx) method to reference a cell or cells to work on. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance and appreciate your support.  The link is very handy.  I can't believe I never came across this issue up to now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You already have your answer:

- first `Select` the worksheet
- the `Select` a range on that worksheet

Your code **will** work if you happen to be on `Sheet1` when it is run, but will fail if you are **not** on `Sheet1`.  *In my opinion VBA is kind of dumb with regard to this issue.*

Comment: more precisely you cannot select a range if sheet isn't activated. Sounds fair IMHO

Comment: @Pierre  Your explanation is better than mine.

Comment: Thank you guys - really appreciate your input.  I was totally unaware of this and I can't believe I never discovered this up to now.  I never use ".select" and it's probably part of the reason.  Thanks for your support guys.