# Select Active Sheet doesnt seem to work

Tags: excel, vba

So I am trying to write a few macros where I adjust various different bits on a worksheet such as clearing contents and reordering. When the sheet in question "MAIN SHEET" is selected (open on the screen) the macros work fine. When I try to run them from a macro button on another sheet they obviously automatically interact with the active sheet in question.

I have tried using the various different commands for making a sheet active / selecting a range but each time it comes up with Run-time Error 9

Any help on what silly mistake I am making is would be much appreciated!

The current incarnation of one of the codes is below

```
    Sub sbClearMainSpreadsheet()
Worksheets("MAIN SHEET").Range("A1:X999").Select

Range("A2:F500").ClearContents
Range("J2:O500").ClearContents
Range("R2:Y500").ClearContents
Range("A2:Y500").Interior.Color = xlNone

If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to clear the Main Spreadsheet?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

End Sub
```

thanks

A

Comment: Try ... Sheets("MAIN SHEET") ... instead

Comment: Is the worksheet that contains the button in a different workbook to your "MAIN SHEET"?  (That's the only reason I can think of that the posted code would give the error you are getting.)

Comment: See [Is the . in .Range necessary when defined by .Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368220/is-the-in-range-necessary-when-defined-by-cells) for related information

Comment: More at [Sheet / Range Select (combined) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792949/sheet-range-select-combined-not-working/39793091#39793091).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Select` the "MAIN SHEET", it's better if you use fully qualified objects.

I think you meant your code to look something like the code below:

```
Sub sbClearMainSpreadsheet()

    ' have the input confirmation box before clearing the contents (not after)
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to clear the Main Spreadsheet?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    With Worksheets("MAIN SHEET")
        .Range("A2:F500, J2:O500, R2:Y500").ClearContents
        .Range("A2:Y500").Interior.Color = xlNone
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe even `.Range("A2:F500, J2:O500, R2:Y500").ClearContents` ...?

Comment: @Jeeped  that w kid be even better ;) I'm not in front of my PC now, I'll update it later.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "Activate" method instead of the "Select" method.

Worksheets("MAIN SHEET").Activate

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838003.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396